# How to display image after using Image Picker and Cropper using GetX in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, rxdart, flutter-getx

I'm using GetX to get the path of Image after the image is cropped and storing it in an RXString on one page:

> ```
> RxString imageAdd = '$imagePath'.obs;
> ```

Then I'm retrieving the Path of the image on another page using:

> ```
> Obx(
>     () => Image(
>  image: AssetImage(
> (pollImageController.imageAdd.value)),
> ```

**But the image is not displaying on the second page.
Complete Code:**

> ```
> ImagePickerCropper Page:
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:get/get.dart';
> import 'package:justpoll/Constants.dart';
> import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
> import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
> import 'dart:io';
> import 'package:justpoll/screens/create_poll/create_poll4.dart';
>
> String imagePath;
>
> class CreatePoll3 extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>   _CreatePoll3State createState() => _CreatePoll3State();
> }
>
> class _CreatePoll3State extends State<CreatePoll3> {
>   final controller = Get.put(PollImageController());
>   File _selectedFile;
>   bool _inProcess = false;
>   final _picker = ImagePicker();
>
>   Widget getImageWidget() {
>     if (_selectedFile != null) {
>       return Image.file(
>         _selectedFile,
>         width: 370,
>         height: 230,
>         fit: BoxFit.cover,
>       );
>     } else {
>       return Padding(
>         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
>         child: Image.asset(
>           "assets/Images/placeholder.png",
>           width: 370,
>           height: 230,
>           fit: BoxFit.cover,
>         ),
>       );
>     }
>   }
>
>   getImage(ImageSource source) async {
>     this.setState(() {
>       _inProcess = true;
>     });
>     PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(source: source);
>
>     if (image != null) {
>       File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
>           sourcePath: image.path,
>           aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 2, ratioY: 1.5),
>           compressQuality: 100,
>           maxWidth: 700,
>           maxHeight: 700,
>           compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
>           androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
>             toolbarColor: Colors.white,
>             toolbarTitle: "Crop Image",
>             statusBarColor: Colors.black,
>             backgroundColor: Colors.white,
>           ));
>
>       imagePath = cropped.path;
>       print(imagePath);
>
>       this.setState(() {
>         _selectedFile = cropped;
>         _inProcess = false;
>       });
>     } else {
>       this.setState(() {
>         _inProcess = false;
>       });
>     }
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return SafeArea(
>       child: Scaffold(
>         backgroundColor: MyColors.white,
>         appBar: AppBar(
>           title: Padding(
>             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
>             child: Text('New Poll'),
>           ),
>           leading: GestureDetector(
>             onTap: () {
>               Navigator.pop(context);
>             },
>             child: Icon(
>               Icons.arrow_back,
>             ),
>           ),
>           backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
>         ),
>         body: ListView(
>           children: [
>             Column(
>               children: [
>                 Center(
>                   child: Padding(
>                     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18, bottom: 28),
>                     child: Text("3/4"),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>
>                 // Padding(
>
>                 //   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 230.0, top: 30, bottom: 30),
>
>                 //   child: Text(
>
>                 //     "Add Image",
>
>                 //     style: TextType.regularDarkText,
>
>                 //   ),
>
>                 // ),
>
>                 getImageWidget(),
>
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
>                   child: Row(
>                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
>                     children: <Widget>[
>                       MaterialButton(
>                         onPressed: () {
>                           getImage(ImageSource.camera);
>                         },
>                         color: Colors.black,
>                         textColor: Colors.white,
>                         child: Icon(
>                           Icons.camera,
>                           size: 24,
>                         ),
>                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>                         shape: CircleBorder(),
>                       ),
>                       MaterialButton(
>                         onPressed: () {
>                           getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
>                         },
>                         color: Colors.black,
>                         textColor: Colors.white,
>                         child: Icon(
>                           Icons.photo_album,
>                           size: 24,
>                         ),
>                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>                         shape: CircleBorder(),
>                       ),
>                       Align(
>                         alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
>                         child: MaterialButton(
>                           onPressed: () {
>                             Navigator.push(
>                               context,
>                               MaterialPageRoute(
>                                 builder: (context) => CreatePoll4(),
>                               ),
>                             );
>                           },
>                           color: Colors.black,
>                           textColor: Colors.white,
>                           child: Icon(
>                             Icons.arrow_forward,
>                             size: 24,
>                           ),
>                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>                           shape: CircleBorder(),
>                         ),
>                       )
>                     ],
>                   ),
>                 ),
>
>                 (_inProcess)
>                     ? Container(
>                         color: Colors.white,
>                         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.95,
>                         child: Center(
>                           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
>                         ),
>                       )
>                     : Center()
>               ],
>             ),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> class PollImageController extends GetxController {
>   RxString imageAdd = '$imagePath'.obs;
>   // adding .obs makes this a stream based observable String
>
> // this onInit override can be used instead of initState in a stateful widget.
> // All text editing controllers can be initialized here
>   @override
>   void onInit() {
>     super.onInit();
>   }
>
>   @override
>   void onClose() {
>     super.onClose();
>   }
> }
> ```

**Image Display Page:**

> ```
> import 'dart:io';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:get/get.dart';
> import 'package:justpoll/Constants.dart';
> import 'package:justpoll/screens/home_page/nav.dart';
> import 'create_poll1_static.dart';
> import 'create_poll3.dart';
>
> final pollDataController = Get.find<PollDataController>();
> final pollImageController = Get.find<PollImageController>();
>
> // final _questionController = pollDataController.questionController;
>
> class CreatePoll4 extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>   _CreatePoll4State createState() => _CreatePoll4State();
> }
>
> class _CreatePoll4State extends State<CreatePoll4> {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return SafeArea(
>       child: Scaffold(
>         backgroundColor: MyColors.white,
>         appBar: AppBar(
>           title: Padding(
>             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
>             child: Text('Poll Preview'),
>           ),
>           leading: GestureDetector(
>             onTap: () {
>               Navigator.pop(context);
>             },
>             child: Icon(
>               Icons.arrow_back,
>             ),
>           ),
>           backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
>         ),
>         body: ListView(
>           children: [
>             Column(
>               children: [
>                 Center(
>                   child: Padding(
>                     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18, bottom: 28),
>                     child: Text("4/4"),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 240, top: 10),
>                   child: Text(
>                     'Select Theme',
>                     style: TextType.regularDarkText,
>                   ),
>                 ),
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
>                   child: Row(
>                     children: [
>                       Expanded(
>                         child: MaterialButton(
>                           onPressed: () {},
>                           color: Colors.yellow,
>                           textColor: Colors.white,
>                           shape: CircleBorder(),
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                       Expanded(
>                         child: MaterialButton(
>                           onPressed: () {},
>                           color: Colors.orange,
>                           textColor: Colors.white,
>                           shape: CircleBorder(),
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                       Expanded(
>                         child: MaterialButton(
>                           onPressed: () {},
>                           color: Colors.brown,
>                           textColor: Colors.white,
>                           shape: CircleBorder(),
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                       Expanded(
>                         child: MaterialButton(
>                           onPressed: () {},
>                           color: Colors.blue,
>                           textColor: Colors.white,
>                           shape: CircleBorder(),
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                       Expanded(
>                         child: MaterialButton(
>                           onPressed: () {},
>                           color: Colors.green,
>                           textColor: Colors.white,
>                           shape: CircleBorder(),
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                       Expanded(
>                         child: MaterialButton(
>                           onPressed: () {},
>                           color: Colors.black,
>                           textColor: Colors.white,
>                           shape: CircleBorder(),
>                         ),
>                       ),
>                     ],
>                   ),
>                 ),
>                 Card(
>                   child: Container(
>                     color: Colors.blue,
>                     child: Padding(
>                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
>                       child: Column(
>                         children: [
>                           Row(
>                             children: [
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
>                                 child: CircleAvatar(
>                                   backgroundImage:
>                                       AssetImage('assets/Images/blackLogo.png'),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
>                                 child: Text('JustPoll'),
>                               ),
>                             ],
>                           ),
>                           Padding(
>                             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
>                             child: Obx(
>                               () => Text(pollDataController.question.value),
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           Padding(
>                             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
>                             child: Obx(
>                               () => Image(
>                                 image: AssetImage(
>                                     (pollImageController.imageAdd.value)),
>                                 height: 150,
>                                 width: 200,
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           Row(
>                             children: [
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 120, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op1.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                               SizedBox(
>                                 width: 70,
>                               ),
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op1Emoji.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                             ],
>                           ),
>                           Row(
>                             children: [
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 120, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op2.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                               SizedBox(
>                                 width: 70,
>                               ),
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op2Emoji.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                             ],
>                           ),
>                           Row(
>                             children: [
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 120, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op3.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                               SizedBox(
>                                 width: 70,
>                               ),
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op3Emoji.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                             ],
>                           ),
>                           Row(
>                             children: [
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 120, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op4.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                               SizedBox(
>                                 width: 70,
>                               ),
>                               Padding(
>                                 padding:
>                                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20),
>                                 child: Obx(
>                                   () => Text(pollDataController.op4Emoji.value),
>                                 ),
>                               ),
>                             ],
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       ),
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
>                   child: Align(
>                     alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
>                     child: MaterialButton(
>                       onPressed: () {
>                         Navigator.push(
>                           context,
>                           MaterialPageRoute(
>                             builder: (context) => Nav(),
>                           ),
>                         );
>                       },
>                       color: Colors.black,
>                       textColor: Colors.white,
>                       child: Icon(
>                         Icons.done,
>                         size: 24,
>                       ),
>                       padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
>                       shape: CircleBorder(),
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 )
>               ],
>             ),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: hi, did you found any solution to this problem? I'm having the same problem also.